# Codeigniter: Call a controller only once when user logs in to show notifications

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have created a notification library to generate different types of notifications for different user groups. What I want is that when a user logged in my `Notifications.php` should be invoked to generate all the notifications for that user. In `Notifications.php` controller I will fetch the data from the database and based on some conditions I will generate a notification. I was thinking of using hooks in CI to do that but the problem is that `Notifications.php` will be invoked every time user move from one page to another page in the application. How can I prevent `Notifications.php` to be invoked multiple times?

Comment: you call the functions in the file only in the routes you want

Comment: @ madalinivascu What if the user visits the same routes?

Comment: you set a session variable after the function calls and you don't call the functions if the variable is set

Comment: @madalinivascu How I can call the controller for a specific route in CI?

Comment: you don't usually call a controller the framework calls the controllers based on your routes,why do you want to do that?

Comment: @madalinivascu I just want to make it like "work in the background" type of the controller. Users will not have direct access to it.

Comment: then you don't need a controller but a simple class that you instantiate in your aplication

Comment: @madalinivascu Ok, I will think about that approach. Thanks for your help.